# Error installing sockets php extension inside docker

Tags: php, docker, sockets

Inside dockerfile:

`docker-php-ext-install sockets`

Gives these errors, on docker build (I used same dockerfile for days but today it appears this new error):

```
/usr/src/php/ext/sockets/sendrecvmsg.c: In function 'init_ancillary_registry':
/usr/src/php/ext/sockets/sendrecvmsg.c:128:19: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct cmsgcred'
  128 |  PUT_ENTRY(sizeof(struct cmsgcred), 0, 0, from_zval_write_ucred,
      |                   ^~~~~~
/usr/src/php/ext/sockets/sendrecvmsg.c:99:17: note: in definition of macro 'PUT_ENTRY'
   99 |  entry.size   = sizev; \
      |                 ^~~~~
/usr/src/php/ext/sockets/sendrecvmsg.c:129:36: error: 'SCM_CREDS' undeclared (first use in this function)
  129 |    to_zval_read_ucred, SOL_SOCKET, SCM_CREDS);
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/php/ext/sockets/sendrecvmsg.c:105:19: note: in definition of macro 'PUT_ENTRY'
  105 |  key.cmsg_type  = type; \
      |                   ^~~~
/usr/src/php/ext/sockets/sendrecvmsg.c:129:36: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  129 |    to_zval_read_ucred, SOL_SOCKET, SCM_CREDS);
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/php/ext/sockets/sendrecvmsg.c:105:19: note: in definition of macro 'PUT_ENTRY'
  105 |  key.cmsg_type  = type; \
      |                   ^~~~
make: *** [Makefile:213: sendrecvmsg.lo] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Answer (score 8):

Adding to the answer posted by @user8998926

You can find several workarounds in the docker-library issue posted here: https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/1245

The easiest being

```
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -D_GNU_SOURCE" docker-php-ext-install sockets
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug in docker images php:8.0.15 and php:8.1.2 for alpine & bullseye.

The fix is pending merge, in my case i've stick with a previous version in order to build.

It's being tracked here:
https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/7978